# Swift spawn nodes infinietly

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, nodes

I am trying to get my nodes to move across the screen and spawn infinitely on a timer. I would aslo like to have multiple nodes on screen at once. This is my stable code so far. I have tried multiple different ways with either freezes or crashes.

```
 let bunnyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "oval 1.png")
    bunny = SKSpriteNode(texture: bunnyTexture)
    bunny.position = CGPoint(x: (size.width / 3), y: 750 + bunny.frame.height)
    self.addChild(bunny)
    bunny.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bunnyTexture.size().height/2)
    bunny.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    let spawnBunny = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.size.height, duration: 4)
    let despawnBunny = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let spawnNdespawn2 = SKAction.sequence([spawnBunny, despawnBunny])
    bunny.runAction(spawnNdespawn2)

    let gobblinTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "oval 2.png")
    gobblin = SKSpriteNode(texture: gobblinTexture)
    gobblin.position = CGPoint(x: 150 + gobblin.frame.width, y: (size.height / 3))
    self.addChild(gobblin)
    let randomGob = arc4random() % UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 2)
    let spawnGob = SKAction.moveByX(+self.frame.size.width, y: 0, duration: 4)
    let despawnGob = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let spawnNdespawn = SKAction.sequence([spawnGob, despawnGob])
    gobblin.runAction(spawnNdespawn)

    let ground = SKNode()
    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, -50))
    ground.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(ground)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SKAction.waitForDuration(interval)` to create a looping timer.

Extend `SKNode` with a new function `loopAction`. This takes a `SKAction` an `NSTimeInterval` and a `() -> Bool` function.

The `SKAction` is the function that will be executed at each interval.
The `() -> Bool` function will be used to stop the otherwise infinite loop.

**Just remember that this captures both the `SKNode` and the `SKAction`. Neither will deallocate until the loop is stopped.**

*Its possible to create an object with a flag (`Bool`) to hold all this information and set the flag to false when it needs to stop. I just prefer this way.*

`LoopActionManager` is an example of how the `loopAction` is implemented.
You need an `SKNode` and an `SKAction`. Instead of calling `runAction` on the `SKNode` you call `loopAction` and pass the interval and the function that controls when to stop. **You would place this code somewhere you have access to the nodes in question.**

*The function to stop can also be implemented as a `trailing closure`*

**Paste the code into a playground to see how it works.**

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground



extension SKNode {

    func loopAction(action:SKAction,interval:NSTimeInterval,continueLoop:() -> Bool) {

        guard continueLoop() else { return }

        runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(interval)) {

            if continueLoop() {
                self.runAction(action)
                self.loopAction(action, interval: interval, continueLoop: continueLoop)
            }
        }
    }
}

// example
class LoopActionManager {

    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
    let action = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 10,dy: 0), duration: 0.5)

    func continueMoveLoop() -> Bool {
        return (node.position.x + node.size.width) < node.scene?.size.width
    }

    func start() {
        node.loopAction(action, interval: 1, continueLoop: continueMoveLoop)
    }

}

let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
let scene = SKScene(size: view.frame.size)
view.presentScene(scene)

let example = LoopActionManager()
scene.addChild(example.node)
example.start()



XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

---

As stated in the comments below it is also possible to use `repeatAction`.
You can extend `SKAction` with a `static func` to generate the `repeatAction` based on an action to repeat and an interval.
In comparison to the first solution this is simpler and more in line with the SDK. You do lose the completion handler for each interval.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import XCPlayground


extension SKAction {

    static func repeatAction(action:SKAction,interval:NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction {

        // diff between interval and action.duration will be the wait time. This makes interval the interval between action starts. Max of 0 and diff to make sure it isn't smaller than 0
        let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(max(0,interval - action.duration))
        let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([waitAction,action])
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceAction)

        return repeatAction

    }
}


let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
let scene = SKScene(size: view.frame.size)
view.presentScene(scene)

let node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))
let action = SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 10,dy: 0), duration: 0.5)

scene.addChild(node)
node.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(action, interval: 1.0))



XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Comment: why is this so complex?  Wouldn't it be easier to place the 2 actions (wait and move) in a sequence, and then use the repeat action.  also, if continue loop is false, why bother with waiting

Comment: @Knight0fDragon `continueLoop()` can/should be evaluated as many times as possible, before and after `wait` both make sense. I just chose after `wait` because then it will be evaluated after the last action has run. If the timing is different this will no longer be true. Looking at `repeatAction`...

Comment: @Knight0fDragon You were right, `repeatAction` does offer a cleaner solution. I added it to my answer. Good call!

Comment: I wouldnt even make it an extension, i would make an action file and use the reference

Comment: @Knight0fDragon extension is more in line with the SDK, that is why I prefer it, but there is no right or wrong here.